# Create an independent contract from another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapps

I have developed a contract and I would make an "initiator" contract which can be contacted with information for creating the first contract and a litle quantity of ethereum (I know, it is not super beacause anybody can decompile the initiator contract with etherscan to optcode and find recompiled code for the first contract but it is more simple by the initiator).

All is good except for creating a independent contract (independent execution, life (if I sucide initiator his children will not die)).

And how to respond with more than set a storage variable with the first contract address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term for the *initiator* is factory. A pretty good example from Hudson Jameson is [Factory.sol](https://gist.github.com/Souptacular/c964f2617d7c8062084a47a12ba79f00), I'll put a slight modified version here.

```
contract Factory {
  bytes32[] public Names;
  address[] public newContracts;

  function createContract (bytes32 name) public {
    address newContract = new Contract(name);
    newContracts.push(newContract);
  } 

  function getName (uint i) public {
    Contract con = Contract(newContracts[i]);
    Names[i] = con.Name();
  }
}

contract Contract {
  bytes32 public Name;

  function Contract (bytes32 name) {
    Name = name;
  }
}
```

To create a new instance of `Contract` you call `Factory.createContract("MyName")`.

Since transaction cannot return a value, a common pattern is to generate an event when you want to return multiple values.

For example if you want to notify the new address and the name of the contract you can do something like this:

```
contract Factory {
  ...
  // Declare event
  event ContractCreated(address _contract, bytes32 _name, uint _index);

  function createContract (bytes32 name) public {
    address newContract = new Contract(name);
    newContracts.push(newContract);

    // Generate event on success
    ContractCreated(newContract, name, newContracts.length - 1);
  }
```